# Fetch data by joining the same table rows based on some id

Tags: mysql, sql, database, hql

I have a table

[image]

and I want to fetch the rows as `area`,`area_name`,`city_size1` `rate`,`city_size2` `rate`,`city_size3` `rate`  grouping based on `area`

[image]

What is the best way to do this

Comment: use group by clause with your query.

Comment: Will there be only 3 different `city_size`? Also post data in table format and mentioned expected output clearly.

Comment: Please show us your expected output.  What you want is not clear to me.

Comment: @Utsav mostly only 3 city size it may change

Answer (score 0):

IF there are only 3 different city_size, you can do it like below. 
Assuming that `AREA_NAME` will also be same for same `area`.

```
select area,area_name
,max(case when city_size=1 
        then rate 
        else null end
    ) as city_size_1_rate
,max(case when city_size=2 
        then rate 
        else null end
    ) as city_size_2_rate
,max(case when city_size=3 
        then rate 
        else null end
    ) as city_size_3_rate   
from your_table
group by area,area_name;
```

Explanation: `case when city_size=1 then rate else null end` will give you `rate` only for `city_size=1` else it will give you `null`. And when you `group by` `area` and select `max` or above value, you will get only the not null `rate`, which will be `city_size_1_rate`. Similarly for other 2 columns.

Comment: But In that I can't select area_name as it is against aggregate query

Comment: not sure what you mean. `area_name` is in the output. Why do you want to select it again?

Comment: area_name is there in the output

Comment: My output will be same as your output. Please run the exact query I gave and then tell me where the problem is.

Comment: Your query is correct but I can't assure  max city size is 3 if one more city size is added what to do

Comment: Then you have to search for `dynamic pivot/unpivot in mysql`

Comment: I am not understand dynamic pivot/unpivot in mysql can you elaborate

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145020/discussion-between-senchu-thomas-and-utsav).

Answer (score 0):

You should use group by here

```
SELECT area,area_name,city_size1 rate,city_size2 rate,city_size3 rate FROM your_table_name GROUP BY area;
```

The group by could be executed like:

- Scan the full table, storing each value of `area` in a
  hashtable
- Return the keys of the hashtable

so optimizes for speed, but potentially requires a amount of memory.